# node-querybuilder: can't set database and user from .ENV file in connection setting

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mysql-connector

I'm using `node-querybuilder` to connect to `mysql`.

this is setting to connect:

```
const settings = {
  host: process.env.HOST_DB,
  database: process.env.NAME_DB,
  user: process.env.USER_DB,
  password: process.env.PASSWORD_DB,
}
```

This is my `.env` file:

```
HOST_DB=localhost
NAME_DB=news
USER_DB=root
PASSWORD_DB=''
```

But it can't connect. If I change `settings` to:

```
const settings = {
  host: process.env.HOST_DB,
  database: 'news',
  user: 'root',
  password: process.env.PASSWORD_DB,
}
```

It's work. Why I can't use `env` variables for `database` and `user`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`node-querybuilder` [default values](https://kylefarris.github.io/node-querybuilder/#connecting-to-your-database) for the host field is `localhost` and for password is `''`, that's why your code works when you just set `database` and `user` manually.

Environment variables set in a `.env` file aren't loaded by default. To have them available under `process.env` you will need to use a library such as `dotenv`.

Instructions on how to use environment variables in NodeJS can be found [here](https://www.webmound.com/nodejs-environment-variables/).